# How to add sql 'when' functionality in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, optional-parameters

I have the following parameters:

```
public object GetDataByProjectCostID(string employeeid, DateTime costdate, int id = 0)
```

And the query:

```
var projectCost = (from pc in db.ProjectCosts
                           where pc.ProjectCostID == id
                           where System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pc.CostDate) == costdate.Date
                          
                           join p in db.Projects
                           on pc.ProjectID equals p.ProjectID

                           join sct in db.SubCostTypes
                           on pc.SubCostTypeID equals sct.SubCostTypeID

                           join ct in db.CostTypes
                           on sct.CostTypeID equals ct.CostTypeID

                           select new
                           {
                               p.ProjectName,
                               ct.CostTypeName,
                               ct.CostTypeID,
                               sct.SubCostTypeName,
                               pc.ProjectID,
                               pc.ProjectCostID,
                               pc.SubCostTypeID,
                               pc.Amount,
                               pc.Quantity,
                               pc.Note,
                               pc.CreatedBy,
                               sct.Unit,
                               pc.CreateDate,
                               pc.CostDate,
                               pc.ProjectCostImage


                           }).ToList();
```

Now my question is how i can add optional parameter in query.
Suppose if id not existed in request then i need to skip the where clause

> where pc.ProjectCostID == id

In sql we can use when clause for that but what for in LINQ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the SQL query you are trying to replicate.

Comment: Construct the main body of your query, omitting the .ToList() at the end. Then simply check whether `id` has a value. If it does, update your query using the fluent syntax. `projectCost = projectCost.Where(item => item.ProjectCostID == id);` Then you can turn that into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 where (( id==0 || pc.ProjectCostID == id)
 && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pc.CostDate) == costdate.Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this technique in LinQ with the LinQ fluent form, you can try this:

```
//Make id nullable
public object GetDataByProjectCostID(string employeeid, DateTime costdate, int? id)
{
var projectCost = (from pc in db.ProjectCosts
                               //This expression is evaluated only if id has a value
                               where (!id.HasValue || pc.ProjectCostID == id)
                               && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(pc.CostDate) == costdate.Date

                               join p in db.Projects
                               on pc.ProjectID equals p.ProjectID

                               join sct in db.SubCostTypes
                               on pc.SubCostTypeID equals sct.SubCostTypeID

                               join ct in db.CostTypes
                               on sct.CostTypeID equals ct.CostTypeID

                               select new
                               {
                                   p.ProjectName,
                                   ct.CostTypeName,
                                   ct.CostTypeID,
                                   sct.SubCostTypeName,
                                   pc.ProjectID,
                                   pc.ProjectCostID,
                                   pc.SubCostTypeID,
                                   pc.Amount,
                                   pc.Quantity,
                                   pc.Note,
                                   pc.CreatedBy,
                                   sct.Unit,
                                   pc.CreateDate,
                                   pc.CostDate,
                                   pc.ProjectCostImage


                               }).ToList();
}
```